# Java regex to match all words in a string

Tags: java, regex, search-multiple-words

I am looking for a regex to match following pattern

```
(abc|def|ghi|abc+def+ghi|def+ghi)
```

essentially everything that's separated by `|` is an OR search
and everything joined with `+` all words must be present.

I have to construct the regex dynamically based on an input string in the above format.

*I tried following for AND searches:*

```
(?=.*?\babc\b)(?=.*?\bdef\b)(?=(.*?\bghi\b)
```

*following for OR searches*

```
.*(abc|def).*
```

Is there a single regex possible? any examples would help

Comment: Provide some valid/invalid input strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
(abc|def|ghi)
```

That will match every string that contains the words you're looking for.

Comment: it won't restrict the search to abc+def+ghi i.e. all three words must be present.

Comment: Why should it restrict the search? Are you not also searching for abc, def, or ghi? Anything that finds those three each alone will also find abc+def+ghi and def+ghi.

Answer (score 1):

### `AND` searches

You list the following:

```
(?=.*?\babc\b)(?=.*?\bdef\b)(?=(.*?\bghi\b)
```

My version:

```
(?=.*?\babc\b)(?=.*?\bdef\b)(?=.*?\bghi\b).
```

Note that your version appears an extra `(` before the `ghi` test.

Also note that I include a `.` at the end (capture any single character), this is so the regular expression actually can match something otherwise you are just doing a lookahead with no actual search.

### `OR` searches

For a search for `"abc" OR "def"` I would use the following regular expression:

```
\babc\b|\bdef\b
```

OR

```
\b(?:abc|def)\b
```

### Combined

So for your example of `(abc|def|ghi|abc+def+ghi|def+ghi)` the actual regular expression might look like this:

```
\babc\b|\bdef\b|\bghi\b|(?=.*?\babc\b)(?=.*?\bdef\b)(?=.*?\bghi\b).|(?=.*?\bdef\b)(?=.*?\bghi\b).
```

It's kind of a bad example because it would match `abc` on it's own because of the first `OR` case instead of the requirement specified by the `AND` case in the middle.

Remember to specify your case sensitivty for the regular expression to.

Answer (score 0):

```
assertTrue(Pattern.matches("\\((\\w+(\\||\\+))+\\w+\\)", "(abc|def|ghi|abc+def+ghi|def+ghi)"));
```

Comment: so if I pass in an input string "hey abc, hi def, yo ghi" how would it match?

Answer (score 0):

Wrote this sample method **match(String input, String searchFilter)**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = " dsfsdf Invalid Locatio sdfsdff Invalid c Test1 xx Test2";
    String searchFilter = "Invalid Pref Code|Invalid Location+Invalid company|Test|Test1+Test2";
    System.out.println(match(input, searchFilter));
}

/**
 * @param input
 * @param searchFilter
 */
private static boolean match(String input, String searchFilter) {
    List<String> searchParts = Arrays.asList(searchFilter.split("\\|"));
    ArrayList<String> ms = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> ps = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String pls : searchParts) {
        if (pls.indexOf("+") > 0) {
            ms.add(pls);
        } else {
            ps.add(pls);
        }
    }
    ArrayList<String> patterns = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String msb : ms) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (String msbp : msb.trim().split("\\+")) {
            sb.append("(?=.*?\\b").append(msbp.trim()).append("\\b).");
        }
        patterns.add(sb.toString());
    }
    Pattern p = Pattern
            .compile("\\b(?:" + StringUtils.join(ps, "|") + ")\\b|"+ StringUtils.join(patterns, "|"), 
                    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    return p.matcher(input).find();
}
```